# I want to find the eigenvectors, so calculate the eigenvalues. Do the following:

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \in M_2[\mathbb{C}]
\end{align*}

I want to find the eigenvectors, so calculate the eigenvalues. Do the following:

the only eigenvalues of $A$ are $\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$ y $\frac{3}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$. To find all the eigenvectors of the matrix, let be

\begin{align*}
v=\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^2
\end{align*}

It is an eigenvector to $\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$ if and only if $v\neq 0$ and $\left( A- \lambda I\right)=0$. This is
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-i\sqrt{11}}{2} & 3 \\
-1 & \frac{-1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}v_1+3v_2 \\
-v_1 + \frac{-1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}v_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align}
\frac{1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}v_1+3v_2 &= 0 \\
-v_1 + \frac{-1-i\sqrt{11}}{2}v_2 &= 0
\end{align}

When solving the system of equations I get two different results, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are $0$ or $v_2$ is anything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Well the 0 vector is always a solution to the equation, but how did you get that $v_2$ was anything? It looks like it should depend on $v_1$

Comment: The arithmetic in these kind of situations is a bit tedious, but if you computed the eigenvalue correctly and subtracted it correctly then you can just plug in, say, $v_1=1$ into the first equation, solve for $v_2$ and then check that the second equation is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is correct, but note that the two equations you arrive at are actually equivalent. Take the first one. Solving for $v_1$, we get
$$v_1 = -3v_2 \bigg(\frac{2}{1-i \sqrt{11}}\bigg),$$
and so
$$v_1 = -3v_2 \bigg(\frac{2}{1-i \sqrt{11}}\bigg) \bigg(\frac{1+i \sqrt{11}}{1+i \sqrt{11}} \bigg),$$
which, after a short computation, gets us
$$v_1 = \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{11}}{2} \bigg) v_2,$$
which is the same as the second equation you got. So we see that an eigenvector is given by
$$(v_1, v_2)= \bigg(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{11}}{2}, 1\bigg).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ and $\bar{\alpha}$ be the eigenvalues of $A.$ Since
$$O=(A-\alpha I)(A-\bar{\alpha}I)=(A-\alpha I)\begin{bmatrix}
2-\bar{\alpha} & \text{--} \\
-1 & \text{--}
\end{bmatrix},$$
$\begin{bmatrix}
2-\bar{\alpha}  \\
-1 
\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for $\alpha.$

Comment: nice!${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Your system of equations to determine the first eigenvalue is correct.

The solution you should get is:

$$v_2 = \left(-\frac{1}{6} + i\frac{\sqrt{11}}{6} \right)v_1$$

or

$$v_1 = \left(- \frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}\right)v_2$$

So the first eigenvector (associated with eigenvalue $\lambda_1= \frac{3}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$) is

$$\mathbf{v}_1 = \pmatrix{ -\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{11}}{2} \\1  }$$

Either by solving a system of equations for the second eigenvalue or by recognizing that $\mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{v}_1^\star$, we obtain the eigenvector associated with $\lambda_2=\lambda_1^\star$:

$$\mathbf{v}_2 = \pmatrix{ -\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{11}}{2} \\1  }.$$